# Updating a table with a groupwise maximum MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I had a table with duplicate user_ids with a many to 1 relationship with tasks and payment.

I used a groupwise maximum on tasks to return the rows that had the highest task completion percentage. However I would like to update this new table with the highest payment completion stats from the same table.

For example:

```
id    date                 taskid  payid  task_completion  pay_value
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  2       3      7.14             0
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  3       3      0.00             0
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  5       3      0.00             0
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  2       6      7.14             40
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  3       6      0.00             40
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  5       6      0.00             40
4724  2007-11-20 15:32:40  4       7      25.71            105
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  7       8      7.14             52
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  8       8      34.29            52
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  10      8      65.71            52
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  7       9      7.14             24
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  8       9      34.29            24
```

So I have used a groupwise maximum on task completion to create a new table (with unique id) as follows:

```
id    date                 taskid  payid  task_completion  pay_value
4722  2007-11-08 16:20:14  2       3      7.14             0
4724  2007-11-20 15:32:40  4       7      25.71            105
4726  2008-01-28 11:44:50  10      8      65.71            52
```

The problem is that for id 4722 the highest pay_value and payid have not been inserted into the resulting table.

I would like to update this in the form (using this select):

```
SELECT 
    s1.payid,
    s1.pay_value,
FROM
    f_tbl s1
        LEFT JOIN
    f_tbl s2 ON s1.cashid = s2.cashid
        AND s1.pay_value > s2.pay_value
WHERE
    s2.cash_id IS NULL
GROUP BY user_id;
```

However it seems that updating the final table based on this query is not possible.
I am stumped, thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Your query selects the minimum pay_value per cashid (so the result you're getting shouldn't be 52 for 4726, but 24) `s1.pay_value > s2.pay_value` should probably be `s1.pay_value < s2.pay_value`

Answer (score 0):

You need a `join` in the `update` to do this.  Assuming your query is correct:

```
update SummaryTable st cross join
       (SELECT s1.payid, s1.pay_value,
        FROM f_tbl s1 LEFT JOIN
             f_tbl s2
             ON s1.cashid = s2.cashid AND s1.pay_value > s2.pay_value
        WHERE s2.cash_id IS NULL
        GROUP BY user_id
       ) toupdate
    set st.payid = toupdate.payid,
        st.pay_value = toupdate.pay_value
    where st.taskid = 4722;
```